# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error using ChromeDriver with Selenium and Linux on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to access and interact with a website using selenium and the chrome driver. I downloaded the chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads),
specifically I downloaded version 2.45 and the linux64 version because I'm on raspberry pi. I also installed geckodriver the arm version for linux. I unzipped both of these files and moved them to my /usr/bin folder because that is where my python 3 path is. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com")
```

I run this code and the error message I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test with selenium.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I checked to make sure chromedriver is an executable file and it is, I know this from looking under properties and permissions and it says anyone can execute the file. I tried installing homebrew (I'm not sure if I did it right) and running brew install chromedriver, still didn't work. Another solution I read online thought I had the wrong chromedriver file for my operation system, but I am pretty sure I do. This is my first time using selenium, so hopefully, I'm not doing it completely wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get chromedriver to work on raspberry pi! The first thing I was doing wrong was using the latest version of chromedriver (version 2.45) which only works for Chrome versions 70-72. Currently (December 2018) the highest version of Chromium (open source Chrome) available on raspberry pi is 65 ([source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=225632)). So that meant that chromedriver versions 2.36 - 2.38 SHOULD work, yet they didn't. Why they still gave me that OS Error, I still don't understand. However I found a useful reddit post (yes, reddit) which I will link [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/7341wt/success_how_to_run_selenium_chrome_webdriver_on/). Basically, instead of downloading chromedriver from their offical website I needed to download it from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/chromium-chromedriver). This website has chromedriver for arm, rather than just linux 64 bit. So I clicked on chromedriver 65 in armhf (updates), and downloaded the .deb file seen on the right side of the page. Then I opened it by double clicking and my raspberry pi unzipped the .deb file and gave me a file named chromedriver located in /usr/lib/chromium-browser. I ran 
    `sudo mv /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin` in terminal to move the chromedriver file to my python directory. Now this piece of selenium code worked perfectly in python and on raspberry pi:

`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Again, I wouldn't have solved this without the helpful reddit post I will link again [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/7341wt/success_how_to_run_selenium_chrome_webdriver_on/). All of the steps I described above are described in the reddit post, I'm just trying to get the word out!

Comment: This approach still works in 2021. Thanks for the detailed description!

Comment: Massive credit needs to go to this answer. I had tried so many online solutions but this still works in 2022. Thanks for the detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

Google's [chromedriver_linux64.zip](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.15/) contains an `amd64/x86-64` binary only, which is the root issue here.

**For Raspberry Pi users:** Pre-built `ARM64` linux chromedriver binaries that will work on Raspberry Pi and others are available in most [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v14.0.0-beta.22) releases. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: As of March '24, the Electron release that contains the right version of Chromedriver for chromium version 104 is https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v20.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** binary which was invoked was not in proper format.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** of the **ChromeDriver** binary format with respect to the underlying *Operating System*.

As you are on **linux64** bit version on **Raspberry Pi** you need to download **chromedriver_linux64.tar.gz** from [chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/), untar it and provide the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* through the argument **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Perform the additional *clean up* tasks:

- ChromeDriver is present in the specified location.
- ChromeDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.

Comment: I still get the same error message with driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')

Comment: @FuturePythonWizard Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: What do you mean when you say Execute your test? I made a non-root user account.

Comment: Do I need to have my chromium be in my /usr/bin directory? Right now its under /usr/share/applications

Answer (score -2):

I took a driver from one of my old projects.
And I was getting the same error.

It turns out that I was trying to run windows chrome driver in Linux.

Dumb me!